# scp not able to write to a mounted volume, complains it's read-only

Tags: filesystems, mount, scp, google-cloud

(Note: though I'm asking a different question here, this is essentially to diagnose the same problem I reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162126/google-compute-engine-reports-a-read-only-disc) on StackOverflow).

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine virtual machine. The image uses Google Container-Optimized OS (if that gets in the way of debugging I'm thinking of switching to Ubuntu instead). I followed the instructions in [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) to format a newly mounted volume on the machine. Specifically, I ran:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/[DEVICE_ID]
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]
sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/[DEVICE_ID] /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]
sudo chmod a+w /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]
```

Where `MNT_DIR` is the directory I was mounting on the device, and `DEVICE_ID` is the name of the device, as per `sudo lsblk` (automatically `sdb`, it seems, not that it matters).

A quick `ls -l /mnt/` shows that the volume *seems* to have mounted correctly, and that there are world read-write-modify permissions to the directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Mar  8 00:00 subway-explorer-datastore
```

OK, now I'd like to transfer some data over to this machine. GCE includes a `google compute scp` command ([documented here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)), which seems like just a thin wrapper on the UNIX `scp` command. So I can use that to write some data off of my local dev machine and onto this cloud disk, right?

So I run:

```
gcloud compute scp ~/Desktop/subway-explorer-api/logbooks.sqlite gke-webapp-default-pool-49338587-d78l:/mnt/subway-explorer-datastore --zone us-central1-a
```

And I get fiddly squat out of it.

```
scp: /mnt/subway-explorer-datastore: Read-only file system
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

The rest of the file system is fine. For example, the following succeeeds:

```
gcloud compute scp ~/Desktop/subway-explorer-api/logbooks.sqlite gke-subway-explorer-default-pool-2bef4d1d-f7dn:/dev/null
```

This is an error raised by `scp`, not by the thin `gcloud` wrapper. To my inexperienced eyes, the permissions on the root folder seem fine. So what are some reasons why `scp` might be throwing this error? How do I debug it?

Comment: This is for a Kubernetes-based application. For context, [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/subway-explorer-deploy) are the deploy files.

Comment: what does `mount | grep /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]` say? (please add output to your question, and not in a comment).  Also, is the mounted dir under `/mnt/` or `/mnt/disks/`?  You seem to be using both in different places - e.g. you're `scp`-ing the file to `/mnt/subway-explorer-datastore`

Comment: Herein lies the answer: I was trying to write to a folder that didn't exist, and misdiagnosing the problem because of the misleading error message. Answer below. Thanks for spotting this (rather dumb) mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As surmised by @cas in the comments, I'm writing it to a folder that doesn't exist. Once I changed the path to `/mnt/subway-explorer-datastore`, it worked correctly.

Recall the error message:

```
scp: /mnt/subway-explorer-datastore: Read-only file system
```

This is misleading! Reading this response I *assumed* (since `scp` can't create folders) that the folder existed, and the problem was that I was missing the right permissions.

I'd like to think that I'd catch this error myself on a fresh cup of coffee.